# I can't reproduce iOS Crash Log

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, crash-log

I am new at mobile development and Xamarin, trying to publish my first iOS app but,
Apple rejected my app due to this crash log :

```
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.6.1 (17G80)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  tid_407  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000185d02df0 0x185cdc000 + 159216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000185c22948 0x185c20000 + 10568
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000185bb1c24 0x185b3c000 + 482340
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000185bb1bb0 0x185b3c000 + 482224
4   SpeedRead.iOS                   0x000000010422b470 undefined
5   SpeedRead.iOS                   0x0000000104220b90 _xamarin_get_block_descriptor
6   SpeedRead.iOS                   0x00000001040e6590 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
7   SpeedRead.iOS                   0x000000010407b3f0 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
8   SpeedRead.iOS                   0x0000000104079dd8 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
9   SpeedRead.iOS                   0x000000010406fbb8 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
10  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x00000001025b66ac _sqlite3_rekey_v2
11  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x000000010232635c _sqlite3_rekey_v2
12  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x000000010232db84 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
13  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x0000000102681d9c _sqlite3_rekey_v2
14  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x0000000102576380 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
15  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x000000010408cff0 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
16  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x00000001041486a4 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
17  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x000000010414bf08 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
18  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x0000000102193a14 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
19  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x0000000102194744 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
20  Foundation                      0x0000000186320f94 0x1861df000 + 1318804
21  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e96d14 0x185dea000 + 707860
22  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e96c68 0x185dea000 + 707688
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e963c4 0x185dea000 + 705476
24  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e911fc 0x185dea000 + 684540
25  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e90bc8 0x185dea000 + 682952
26  GraphicsServices                0x00000001902725cc 0x19026f000 + 13772
27  UIKitCore                       0x000000018a043744 0x1895d5000 + 10938180
28  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x00000001026cc238 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
29  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x0000000102635ef0 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
30  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x0000000102635e74 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
31  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x00000001021b9f64 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
32  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x0000000102576380 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
33  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x000000010408cff0 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
34  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x00000001041486a4 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
35  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x000000010414e8fc _sqlite3_rekey_v2
36  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x000000010406b5a8 _sqlite3_rekey_v2
37  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x0000000104228594 undefined
38  SpeedRead.iOS                   0x00000001021b9ebc _sqlite3_rekey_v2
39  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000185d0d384 0x185d0c000 + 4996
```

I can't reproduce this crash at visual studio, i tried with all simulators but it works fine. Apple review says :

[image: applereview]

Buttons open pages which is reading database with entity framework and sqllite.
( here is soure code : https://github.com/fatihmgenc/SpeedRead , pages are AntrenmanPage & MetinEklemePage )

I use Ad-hoc for upload app to store-connect and my build settings :

[image: buildsettings]

What do you suggest me at this point ?

Comment: Did you debug run this on iOS same version?

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with your SQLite database, as you can see it says that the `_sqlite3_rekey_v2` is undefined. Most likely when you tested before submission, you forgot to delete the app from your device, along with the your cache and the temp files on the computer.

If you follow the buttons clicks to what they are saying, the bug is in the `Antrenman` page, and it's related to your SQLite database, so it could be in [this line](https://github.com/fatihmgenc/SpeedRead/blob/960dac2e8e86d6c9bc8ba7d673475b97ccd2f6f8/SpeedRead/SpeedRead/Pages/AntrenmanPage.xaml.cs#L35) or in [this line](https://github.com/fatihmgenc/SpeedRead/blob/960dac2e8e86d6c9bc8ba7d673475b97ccd2f6f8/SpeedRead/SpeedRead/ViewModels/AntrenmanViewModel.cs#L386). So try to place a `try-catch` around those two lines and inside the catch, tell the code what it should do when the previous line was not called.

Comment: Thanks for your answering i couldn't try your suggestion because now i have another trouble like i mention here before:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/184164/ios-crash-log
when i debug/deploy my app to simulator it is not opening directly, it closes after launch screen and i click then it runs normally. I jump on this problem with closing hot reload but now it is appears again. this is the video that explains the problem : https://streamable.com/rufqie
I tried with another example app, it opens fine. But my app is closing like this ( debug is not ending and there isn't any error

Comment: Yes it didn't hit the breakpoints also, Now i tried with another simulator ( iPhone 11 iOS 13.6 ) it works, this issue ( that is about closing after launchscreen ) is not exist at this simulator . Breakpoints hits also and didn't go inside the catch lines, passed smoothly on try. I removed app from simulator before try, I also clean project and deleted obj&bin files inside the iOS project, what should i also clean before debug ? –

Comment: Hmm thats very strange. Try to test with different scenarios and make it break